# Without using auth middleware, how to get user id by token?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

In Laravel 5.4, using oauth2/passport, I've a route that is public - so I don't use middleware auth.

This route is accessed by users logged in and not logged in.

I want to take the user id o who is accessing this route (if is logged in). Without pass the user id by parameter or something like this, is it possible (just with token)?

I can get user token by:

```
$access_token = $request->header('Authorization');
```

And return like this:

```
"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjlmZGIwZGM0MzgyZjI4MzNjZTJkMzk5M2M2NzBmYWZiNWE3ZTdiODhhZGE4NWY0OTBhYmI5MGFjMjExODAyNzIwYTBmYzczOTJjM2YyZTdjIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiOWZkYjBkYzQzODJmMjgzM2NlMmQzOTkzYzY3MGZhZmI1YTdlN2I4OGFkYTg1ZjQ5MGFiYjkwYWMyMTE4MDI3MjBhMGZjNzM5MmMzZjJlN2MiLCJpYXQiOjE0ODc4NTU2MTYsIm5iZiI6MTQ4Nzg1NTYxNiwiZXhwIjoxNDg3OTQyMDE2LCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbIioiXX0.sdHNQ_bDGtO3lGBwtmlZfkSdYkaUsYSabaY93894Fw4l3z_wU5d7xsfNj6LoK8lPXBTFAhoFf7SjtuQ0F_T6lst0ADwEmc_fLTH1dsTkHq6BdOLr3Ur6dLrbYOqihHG0FhJ6HaUtanbRBBeuK33aVUwuUkCwVkrLgxK6OYEwcq97aU1Cuy3jHOfOB88VAuJ42kwtScpXzi0Oo6zlCxyGAmBlEMWdcSBEkI4vRR-cJdaWsRVZ--671i1Gw5jOhXtN0HS_HMNSf9WWgiUDAyhe1mvlW4eZbTDfg2Al34YauJ_rpPSCw6vwnvpqp9Yvh9Vl0r1k8o_bm_2-NjiVINqdRALmaORbFGu2S9CJso5Jcio_jrWSzznIkf6Jopw9ar8Ca_Cf_KV6cmLOOx2XgWXV7WMCkSIPQXFXrtxE4hnfXEd8K5S5HLgch0hPgJPpgL91x1i73MP1gQyYoWNFCip9cDDlDvPO1zG28O12c4H4bsdy1jaaOOOv34yECfgA87RIFCbGtrzd_9QBXDse51L1IFJu8B6sotyk_4QcGcKSWzOPjI8L2_xhPIG54qk0lzqNWeVHo2UbNpBB6u2OJnszKC44BH5hneYoTbqMGK_1Uo2jR14XixvBlZydXXquuTmDVoBj2ygfjlnZ6UWJenQIO_bLEkF2iaWcgbOhJ6S197k"
```

I don't know how to locate user by this token.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need the auth middleware to be enabled. You can use `auth('api')->user()` to get the active user. It will be null if no token is present.

Answer (score 4):

To get the user by the token, you need to understand what the token is.

The token is broken up into three base64 encoded parts: the header, the payload, and the signature, separated by periods. In your case, since you're just wanting to find the user, you just need the `header`

To get the header, you can do something like this:

```php
// break up the string to get just the token
$auth_header = explode(' ', $access_token);
$token = $auth_header[1];
// break up the token into its three parts
$token_parts = explode('.', $token);
$token_header = $token_parts[0];

// base64 decode to get a json string
$token_header_json = base64_decode($token_header);
// you'll get this with the provided token:
// {"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","jti":"9fdb0dc4382f2833ce2d3993c670fafb5a7e7b88ada85f490abb90ac211802720a0fc7392c3f2e7c"}

// then convert the json to an array
$token_header_array = json_decode($token_header_json, true);
```

Once you have this, you can find the user's token in the `jti` key:

```php
$user_token = $token_header_array['jti'];
```

And you can get the user using that:

```php
// find the user ID from the oauth access token table
// based on the token we just got
$user_id = DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')->where('id', $user_token)->value('user_id');

// then retrieve the user from it's primary key
$user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
```

[More info on jwt's.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token)

Comment: how can I send the token with request body and check if the user authorised or not I don't want to use header

Comment: So the user id is not in the JWT payload?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $user = Auth::guard('users')->user();
 $name = $user->name;
```